# Custom Finder Selection Color

Tags: macbook-pro, finder, color

I visited the Apple Store yesterday to try out the new MacBook Pro with Touch Bar.

The Finder has a really nice black selection when clicking on an item. I can reproduce it by changing the selection color in Settings.app.

[image]

However, I don't want to change the selection color for the entire system as text becomes unreadable when the selection is black.

Is there a way to change the selection color only for the Finder? Maybe something new to Sierra? The MacBook Pro in the Apple Store had the default blue selection color, only the Finder was black.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this black Finder highlight may be a Sierra bug rather than an advanced configuration setting.

See two related examples of Sierra Finder black highlighting being reported as a bug:

- [Why is my Finder highlight color becomes black?](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7751274?start=0&tstart=0)
- [Sierra finder text turning black over black](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7675362?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: I see. I thought that this might be an exclusive feature for newer Macs like the black boot screen. (Mine is still white - 2011 MBP)

Comment: But as only very few people seem to see the black Finder, it probably is a bug, thanks!